# Error: failed to process not implemented: regenerator: complex pattern in catch clause -- In NextJs 12

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
after compile my page it shows an error that said:
wait - compiling...
thread '' panicked at 'not implemented: regenerator: complex pattern in catch clause', C:\Users\runneradmin.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\swc_ecma_transforms_compat-0.47.1\src\es2015\regenerator\case.rs:1232:30
error - ./pages/auth/index.tsx
Error: failed to process not implemented: regenerator: complex pattern in catch clause
```

maybe its cause by SWC but it so ambiquous and nothing help me to figure out what exactly caused this error !

Comment: It seems that Next12 + SWC is not ready. I've downgraded to next@11.1.2 + Babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beacuse we use {} in catch block and swc cant figure out what is destructuring !

```
   const handleSubmit = useMutation(async () => {
        try {
            const res = await gate.register({ username: phoneNumber });
            setstep((prev) => prev + 1);
            toast.success(res.message);
        } catch ({ data: { errors } }) { // this line throw error remove {data:{error}} and put just e
            showErrorMessage(errors);
        }
    });
```

**true implemention**

```
   const handleSubmit = useMutation(async () => {
        try {
            const res = await gate.register({ username: phoneNumber });
            setstep((prev) => prev + 1);
            toast.success(res.message);
        } catch (e) { // this line throw error remove {data:{error}} and put just e
            showErrorMessage(e.data.error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same exact problem. Thanks :)